# Create a pandas Dataframe from Json

Tags: python, pandas

I tried this to create seperate tables to store my project in a mysql DB and for the first two steps it works perfectly.
But when i try to use the same routine to write the 'content' it creates a a DataFrame is not properly called result.
Any ideas how to fix that?
I searched in stackoverflow for the failure but couldn´t apply those results to my problem.

```
 for i in range(len(data)):
    user = data[i]['user']
    if len(user['descriptionUrls']) == 0:
        user['descriptionUrls'] = None
    user_df = pandas.DataFrame(pandas.json_normalize(user))
    user_df.to_sql(name='user', con=con, if_exists='append', index=False)

    men_user = data[i]['mentionedUsers']
    men_user_df = pandas.DataFrame(men_user).applymap(str)
    men_user_df.to_sql(name='mentionedusers', con=con, if_exists='append', index=False) 

    tweet_content = data[i]['content']
    tweet_content_df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(tweet_content)
    tweet_content_df.to_sql(name='content', con=con, if_exists='append', index=False)
    print(tweet_content)
```

Comment: `pandas.json_normalize` itself returns a dataframe, why are you passing it back to `pandas.DataFrame` ?

Comment: I found that way here, but you are absolutly right. Thanks for the information.